Long nicematrix with color and margin text
I currently would like to have a matrix that is long and includes some color on each row. However, whenever I use the & multiple times, I get an error saying I have an extra alignment tab that has changed to \cr. I've looked into this and this seems to reference that I have an extra &, but after checking again, this wasn't it. My code is as follows
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,matrix,positioning,fit, decorations.pathreplacing}
\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{20}
\usepackage[left=1in,top=1in,right=1in,bottom=1in,nohead,paperwidth=8.5in, paperheight=11in]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \[
\NiceMatrixOptions{xdots={horizontal-labels,line-style = <->}}
\setlength\arraycolsep{6pt}  % Horizontal height
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.8}  % Vertical height
    \begin{pNiceMatrix}%
[   margin,
    last-col,
  ]
    \Block[fill=red!15,rounded-corners]{1-2}{} a & & & & b & \Vdotsfor{4}^{\text{State 1}} \\
    a & & & &  b & \\
    a & & & &  b & \\
    a & & & &  b & \\
    \Block[fill=red!15,rounded-corners]{1-2}{} a & & & & b & \Vdotsfor{4}^{\text{State 1}} \\
    a & & & &  b & \\
    a & & & &  b & \\
    a & & & &  b & \\
    \Block[fill=red!15,rounded-corners]{1-2}{} a & & & &  b & \Vdotsfor{4}^{\text{State 1}} \\
    a & & & &  b & \\
    a & & & &  b & \\
    a & & & &  b & \\
    \Block[fill=red!15,rounded-corners]{1-2}{} a & & & &  b & \Vdotsfor{4}^{\text{State 1}} \\
    a & & & &  b & \\
    a & & & &  b & \\
    a & & & &  b & \\
    \Block[fill=red!15,rounded-corners]{1-2}{} a & & & &  b & \Vdotsfor{4}^{\text{State 1}} \\
    a & & & &  b & \\
    a & & & &  b & \\
    a & & & &  b & \\
    \end{pNiceMatrix}
    \]
\end{figure}

\end{document}

When I remove three ampersands between a and b in each row, the result compiles. However, my idea was to have continuous dots between a and b to make a long matrix, combined with the arrows on the margins. For reference, in this MWE, I also have the nicematrix.sty file on my overleaf which can be found on www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/nicematrix/nicematrix.sty.

I have no problem compiling your code. You should try to delete the aux file (in Overleaf: Logs and output files (near Recompile) and Clear cached files (in red)) and compile again.

This has fixed my problem. Thank you!

I’m voting to close this question because it was fixed in comments.
